# Any jquery plugin for image thumbnail gallery with description in popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup, thumbnails, image-gallery

I'm searching the internet for a jquery plugin for image thumbnail gallery with description in popup.. But I didn't get a suitable one till now.. 
I need next and previous buttons in popup which will show next or previous item description on button click (slide the content in popup)..

Can anyone suggest a plugin for me..? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Check this out, you can find one here*

[37 Fresh Jquery Image plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/)